# pegar elemento superior selenium, python, scraping

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
<div class="cell-list-content-icon">
<span><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>EMPRESA XXXXXXXX</span>
<span><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>Remoto</span>
<span><i class="fa fa-building"></i>Grande empresa</span>
<span><i class="far fa-money-bill-alt"></i>R$7.000</span>
<span><i class="far fa-chart-bar"></i>Pleno</span><span>
<i class="far fa-file-alt"></i>CLT</span>
<span><i class="fas fa-plane"></i>Aceita candidatos de fora</span></div>
```

Como faço para pegar o valor "R$7.000

```
<span><i class="far fa-money-bill-alt"></i>R$7.000</span>
```

Ele está dentro das chaves SPAN
Consigo localizar o id = "far fa-money-bill-alt"

Mas o Valor está em uma marcação superior ou pai, marcação span

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
html = """
<div class="cell-list-content-icon">
<span><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>EMPRESA XXXXXXXX</span>
<span><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>Remoto</span>
<span><i class="fa fa-building"></i>Grande empresa</span>
<span><i class="far fa-money-bill-alt"></i>R$7.000</span>
<span><i class="far fa-chart-bar"></i>Pleno</span><span>
<i class="far fa-file-alt"></i>CLT</span>
<span><i class="fas fa-plane"></i>Aceita candidatos de fora</span></div>
"""
belo = bs(html, 'html5lib')
spans = belo.find_all('span')
spans[3].text
```

edit:

Com Selenium depois do driver criado usa o método:
`.find_element_by_xpath('//div/span[3]/text()')`